# Showing images in Datatables columns

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have the following datatable definition:

```
 $("#tblSteps").dataTable({
        sAjaxSource: '@Url.Action("GetAllOpenCandidateSteps")?' + "candidateId=" + $("#txtCandidateId").val(),
        bJQueryUI: true,
        dom: 'T<"clear">rti',
        bAutoWidth: false,
        "bPaginate" : false,
        "oLanguage": {
            sEmptyTable: "There are no Steps at this time"
        },
        "aoColumns": [
            { "sWidth": "1%", sClass: "smallFonts" },
            { "sWidth": "1%", sClass: "smallFonts" },
            { "sWidth": "5%", sClass: "smallFonts" },
            { "sWidth": "19%", sClass: "smallFonts" },
            { "sWidth": "19%", sClass: "smallFonts" },
            { "sWidth": "19%", sClass: "smallFonts" },
            { "sWidth": "19%", sClass: "smallFonts" },
            {
                "sWidth": "19%", sClass: "smallFonts", "sName": "CandidateId", "mRender": function (data, type, row) {
                    var chk = row[7] == 'True' ? ' checked="true" ' : ' ';
                    var chk1;
                    if (chk === ' ')
                        chk1 = "false";
                    else
                        chk1 = "true";
                    if (chk1 == "true") {
                        return "<img height='16' width='16' src='/Images/yes.gif'></img><label style='font-size:x-small'>Complete</label>";
                    }
                    else {
                        return "<img height='16' width='16' src='/Images/button_red.png'></img><label style='font-size:x-small'>Not Complete</label>";
                    }
                    //return "<input type='checkbox'" + chk + " id='chkuar" + row[0] + "' onchange=approved('" + row[0] + "','" + row[1] + "'," + chk1 + "); >";
                }
            }
        ],
        tableTools: {
            "sSwfPath": "../../Scripts/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf", //'<c:url value="../../scripts/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"/>', //"//cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.2/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf", // 
            "aButtons": [
                {
                    "sExtends": "print",
                    "bShowAll": true
                }
            ]

        }
    });
```

You'll see in the last column I am displaying an image from the Images folder.  This shows up on my DEV box using Casinni but not on the server.  Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Might seem obvious, but is the image definitely on the server?

Comment: @markpsmith - Yes, I can see them both in the Images folder.

Comment: Can you see the HTML that's rendered for the image? Is the path wrong?

Comment: Using Browser developer tools : Network tab or Console, try and see if its showing any errors (eg 404) for the image under question, on server.

Comment: @AnkitMishra and Mark - I use F12 (IE) to display the HTML and I see the rendered table properly display with the row showing:

     <td width="16" height="16" src="/Images/button_red.png"></img>
     <label style="font-size: x-small;">Not Complete</label>

Comment: Try opening the image in separate tab by using URL like `<your server>/Images/button_red.png` (e.g. if you server is example.com; use example.com/Images/button_red.png). And check if its there.

Comment: Well something's wrong there for sure - where's the opening `img` tag?

Comment: @markpsmith - I entered that info by hand so I missed the img tag...

Comment: @AnkitMishra - I can see both images when I do enter in the browser address, no problem.  Any other ideas?

Comment: `img` tags are self closing, does this work: `<img height='16' width='16' src='/Images/yes.gif'/>`?

Comment: @annoyingmouse - Thanks, but I already tried that.  I am really stumped on this one.  Anyone??

Comment: @Dean.DePue And are you getting an issue with the developer consoles network tab - is it getting the image? If you page is located here `http://<example.com>/<someDirectory>/` and your images are located here: `http://<example.com>/Images/` then your `src` should be `../Images/yes.gif`. The `..` represents moving up a level in the directory hierarchy. It really does sound as though you're not referencing the images location correctly. It might be worthwhile using the full URL of the image like this: `<img height='16' width='16' src='http://<example.com>/Images/yes.gif'/>`?

Comment: @annoyingmouse - that was indeed the problem, adding the ".." before the location worked just fine.  Please submit an answer so I can give you the credit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems as though the image was being pulled from the wrong URI; if the table is located on a page with a URI like this: `http://<example.com>/<someDirectory>/` and the image is located at this URI: `http://<example.com>/Images/yes.gif` then the correct `src` for the image should be: `../Images/yes.gif` in order to reflect the directory hierarchy. Glad it helped ;-)